# getting derivations out of typeclass resolution

Tags: haskell, constraints, typeclass

We can get a value level proof that `[Int]` has a Show instance using a  `Dict`

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds, GADTs #-}
data Dict (p :: Constraint) where
  Dict :: p => Dict p
```

and

```
proof = Dict :: Dict (Show [Int])
```

Is there a way to get a value level derivation, that is, the entire proof tree ?

```
derivation = Apply@Int(Lam a.(Show a) :=> Show [a])) (Apply(() :=> Show Int)())
```

Answer (score 4):

There isn't a way to get the derivation of an arbitrary constraint as a Haskell value.

The closest thing I can think of, if you want to check whether the derivation is what you think it is, is to look at the desugarer output.

```
ghc -ddump-ds -ddump-to-file A.hs
```

The relevant part looks like this:

```
-- RHS size: {terms: 2, types: 1, coercions: 0, joins: 0/0}
irred :: Show [Int]
[LclId]
irred = GHC.Show.$fShow[] @ Int GHC.Show.$fShowInt

-- RHS size: {terms: 2, types: 3, coercions: 0, joins: 0/0}
proof :: Dict (Show [Int])
[LclIdX]
proof = Cns.Dict @ (Show [Int]) irred
```

Another one is to write custom typeclasses instrumented to reflect the  derivation, either in types or in values, but of course this doesn't apply to preexisting type classes.

```
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes, ConstraintKinds, GADTs, DataKinds,
   FlexibleInstances, KindSignatures, MultiParamTypeClasses, RankNTypes,
   ScopedTypeVariables, TypeApplications, TypeOperators,
   UndecidableInstances #-}

import Data.Typeable
import Data.Kind

data (c :: [Type]) :=> (d :: Type -> Constraint)

class MyShow a d where
  myshow :: a -> String

instance (d ~ ('[] :=> MyShow Int)) => MyShow Int d where

instance (MyShow a da, d ~ ('[da] :=> MyShow [a])) => MyShow [a] d where

myshowInstance :: forall a d. (Typeable d, MyShow a d) => TypeRep
myshowInstance = typeRep @_ @d Proxy

main = print (myshowInstance @[Int])
```

The output could be made to look better, e.g., via a singleton with a proper rendering method instead of `TypeRep`, but I hope you get the main idea.

```
:=> (': * (:=> ('[] *) (MyShow Int)) ('[] *)) (MyShow [Int])
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be what you're after, or at least enough to give you a general idea. I can't think of a way to have GHC provide this automatically, but you can manually construct the chain of entailments that proves the constraint using the `constraints` package.

For whatever reason, there is no `instance () :=> Show Int`, so I've used `Char` instead. This is likely an oversight, I've opened a pull request to add the missing instances.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}

import Data.Constraints

derivation :: () :- Show [Char]
derivation = trans showList showChar
    where showList :: Show a :- Show [a]
          showList = ins

          showChar :: () :- Show Char
          showChar = ins
```

Unfortunately printing this value doesn't show the inner derivations, just `"Sub Dict"`.

A fun exercise could be to try to write `derivation` with explicit `TypeApplications` using `Data.Constraint.Forall`. You'll need a couple extra steps to prove `Show a :- Forall Show` and `ForallF Show [] :- Show [a]`.

Comment: That would be a fun exercice indeed !